# Postgresql memory use invokes OOM killer

Tags: linux, postgresql

I am using Debian 9 on a device with 512 MB of RAM and an 8 GB disk.
I have installed PostgreSQL 9.6.22 with the extension TimescaleDB 1.7.1.
PostgreSQL memory-related parameters are the following:

```
shared_buffers = 128MB                  # min 128kB
#temp_buffers = 8MB                     # min 800kB
#work_mem = 4MB                         # min 64kB
#maintenance_work_mem = 64MB            # min 1MB
#autovacuum_work_mem = -1               # min 1MB, or -1 to use maintenance_work_mem
dynamic_shared_memory_type = posix      # the default is the first option
                                        # use none to disable dynamic shared memory
max_connections = 13                    # (change requires restart)
#superuser_reserved_connections = 3     # (change requires restart)
```

Recently, the OOM killer has appeared and it looks like PostgreSQL is taking up the most memory:

```
 postgres invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x26084c0, order=0, oom_score_adj=0
 postgres cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
 CPU: 0 PID: 11632 Comm: postgres Not tainted 4.4.0-cip #1
 Hardware name: Generic AM33XX (Flattened Device Tree)
 [<c00133d0>] (unwind_backtrace) from [<c0011cdc>] (show_stack+0x10/0x14)
 [<c0011cdc>] (show_stack) from [<c00dca94>] (dump_header+0x4c/0x180)
 [<c00dca94>] (dump_header) from [<c00a38e4>] (oom_kill_process+0x6c/0x39c)
 [<c00a38e4>] (oom_kill_process) from [<c00a3e54>] (out_of_memory+0x1d8/0x2fc)
 [<c00a3e54>] (out_of_memory) from [<c00a7ecc>] (__alloc_pages_nodemask+0x830/0x89c)
 [<c00a7ecc>] (__alloc_pages_nodemask) from [<c00c012c>] (__pte_alloc+0x20/0x1b0)
 [<c00c012c>] (__pte_alloc) from [<c00c209c>] (handle_mm_fault+0x224/0xc80)
 [<c00c209c>] (handle_mm_fault) from [<c04be4b0>] (do_page_fault+0x20c/0x35c)
 [<c04be4b0>] (do_page_fault) from [<c000923c>] (do_DataAbort+0x38/0xb8)
 [<c000923c>] (do_DataAbort) from [<c04bdebc>] (__dabt_usr+0x3c/0x40)
 Exception stack(0xdb95bfb0 to 0xdb95bff8)
 bfa0:                                     aaf9a000 00000000 00101002 aaf9a008
 bfc0: b6a5d7a4 00101000 00098dd6 b6a5d7d4 00100008 b6a5d000 000001ff b6a4185c
 bfe0: 000000c0 bed9f978 b6a052d7 b69c444c 40070030 ffffffff
 Mem-Info:
 active_anon:113550 inactive_anon:651 isolated_anon:0
                              active_file:69 inactive_file:126 isolated_file:0
                              unevictable:0 dirty:0 writeback:0 unstable:0
                              slab_reclaimable:1250 slab_unreclaimable:2180
                              mapped:34529 shmem:35279 pagetables:         free:8083 free_pcp:0 free_cma:2861
 Normal free:32332kB min:16384kB low:20480kB high:24576kB active_anon:454200kB inactive_anon:2604kB active_file:276kB inactive_file:504kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:524288kB managed:511816kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:138116kB shmem:141116kB slab_reclaimable:5000kB slab_unreclaimable:8720kB kernel_stack:1136kB pagetables:4776kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:11444kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:4960 all_unreclaimable? yes
 lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0
 Normal: 989*4kB (UMEHC) 397*8kB (UMEH) 215*16kB (UMEHC) 138*32kB (UMEHC) 67*64kB (UEH) 12*128kB (UEC) 1*256kB (U) 0*512kB 1*1024kB (C) 1*2048kB (C) 2*4096kB (C) 0*8192kB = 32332kB
 35474 total pagecache pages
 0 pages in swap cache
 Swap cache stats: add 0, delete 0, find 0/0
 Free swap  = 0kB
 Total swap = 0kB
 131072 pages RAM
 0 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
 3118 pages reserved
 4096 pages cma reserved
 [ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss nr_ptes nr_pmds swapents oom_score_adj name
 [  220]     0   220    36222      113      64       0        0             0 systemd-journal
 [  247]     0   247     3154      103       7       0        0         -1000 systemd-udevd
 [  352]  1000   352     4778       31       6       0        0             0 custom-process
 [  353]  1000   353     6572       35       5       0        0             0 custom-process2
 [  356]  1000   356     4778       46       5       0        0             0 custom-process3
 [  358]     0   358     1163       55       5       0        0             0 cron
 [  368]  1000   368     4778       32       7       0        0             0 custom-process4
 [  377]   107   377     1332      104       6       0        0          -900 dbus-daemon
 [  385]     0   385     1795      212       7       0        0             0 openvpn
 [  389]  1000   389     5477       55       7       0        0             0 custom-process5
 [  405]     0   405     1524      105       5       0        0             0 systemd-logind
 [  408]  1000   408     7084       40       8       0        0             0 custom-process6
 [  412]     0   412     1100       54       6       0        0             0 cgmanager
 [  416]  1000   416     6572       41       6       0        0             0 custom-process7
 [  422]     0   422     2488       33       3       0        0             0 custom-process8
 [  526]   109   526    47120     2045      22       0        0          -900 postgres
 [  530]   109   530    47145    32270      84       0        0             0 postgres
 [  531]   109   531    47120      538      18       0        0             0 postgres
 [  532]   109   532    47120     1343      19       0        0             0 postgres
 [  533]   109   533    47206      542      21       0        0             0 postgres
 [  534]   109   534    12158      325      16       0        0             0 postgres
 [  535]   109   535    47187      500      20       0        0             0 postgres
 [  537]   109   537    96668    51046     124       0        0             0 postgres
 [  564]     0   564     1315      174       6       0        0             0 dhclient
 [  641]     0   641     2125      134       7       0        0         -1000 sshd
 [  643]     0   643      923       29       5       0        0             0 agetty
 [  646]     0   646      868       29       5       0        0             0 agetty
 [  675]   105   675     1993      408       7       0        0             0 ntpd
 [29365]     0 29365    10566      333      15       0        0             0 packagekitd
 [29371]     0 29371     9412      435      14       0        0             0 polkitd
 [29655]     0 29655    10825      268      13       0        0             0 nginx
 [29656]    33 29656    10876      319      13       0        0             0 nginx
 [19701]  1000 19701    42241     7379     114       0        0             0 node
 [11625]   109 11625    47909    17171      85       0        0             0 postgres
 [11629]   109 11629    47775    15420      84       0        0             0 postgres
 [11631]   109 11631    50664     6973      58       0        0             0 postgres
 [11632]   109 11632    50987     6972      58       0        0             0 postgres
 [11633]   109 11633    50986     6982      58       0        0             0 postgres
 [11634]   109 11634    50985     6986      58       0        0             0 postgres
 [11635]   109 11635    50987     6981      58       0        0             0 postgres
 [11636]   109 11636    50987     6981      58       0        0             0 postgres
 Out of memory: Kill process 537 (postgres) score 399 or sacrifice child
 Killed process 537 (postgres) total-vm:386672kB, anon-rss:19679
```

Here is PostgreSQL log at that time:

```
[526] LOG:  worker process: TimescaleDB Background Worker Scheduler (PID 537) was terminated by signal 9: Killed
[526] LOG:  terminating any other active server processes
[11629] postgres@db WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
[11629] postgres@db DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit,
 because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
[11629] postgres@db HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
[11625] postgres@db WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
[11625] postgres@db DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit,
 because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
[11625] postgres@db HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
[533] WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
[533] DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another
 server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
[533] HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
[11632] postgres@db WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
[11632] postgres@db DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit,
 because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
[11632] postgres@db HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
[11635] postgres@db WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
[11635] postgres@db DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit,
 because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
[11635] postgres@db HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
[11631] postgres@db WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
[11631] postgres@db DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit,
 because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
[11631] postgres@db HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
[11634] postgres@db WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
[11634] postgres@db DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit,
 because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
[11634] postgres@db HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
[11633] postgres@db WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
[11633] postgres@db DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit,
 because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
[11633] postgres@db HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
[11636] postgres@db WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
[11636] postgres@db DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit,
 because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
[11636] postgres@db HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
[526] LOG:  all server processes terminated; reinitializing
[11637] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2022-09-12 21:47:45 CEST
[11637] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
[11637] LOG:  redo starts at 1C/32C6E978
[11637] LOG:  invalid record length at 1C/32D041F8: wanted 24, got 0
[11637] LOG:  redo done at 1C/32D041D0
[11637] LOG:  last completed transaction was at log time 2022-09-12 21:50:23.799706+02
[11637] LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
[11641] LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
[526] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
[11643] LOG:  TimescaleDB background worker launcher connected to shared catalogs
```

I know there is [overcommit tuning available](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/kernel-resources.html#LINUX-MEMORY-OVERCOMMIT) and that there may be an underlying issue with my application that makes calls to PostgreSQL but I would like to understand PostgreSQL use of memory. I have tried to understand the OOM Killer output and PostgreSQL memory-related parameters but I have several doubts:

- What is the max number of processes of PostgreSQl? I thought it would correspond to the number of maximum connections (`max_connections + superuser_reserved_connections`). However, this limit adds up to 13 in this case while there are 16 postgres processes.
- According to the interpretation of OOM killer output described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43611576/3094722) and [here](https://community.wandisco.com/s/article/Guide-to-Out-of-Memory-OOM-events-and-decoding-their-logging), the actual RAM in use is the sum of `rss` values. However, in this case the sum adds up to 187604 pages ≈730 MB, which is more than the total RAM in the device.
- What is the maximum memory a PostgreSQL may use? According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61348800/3094722), `max RAM = shared_buffers + (temp_buffers + work_mem) * max_connections`. In this case, 128 + (8+4)*10 = 248MB.
  However, the OOM Killer output does not match this assumption. Total rss for postgres processes is ≈ 690MB, much more than it should and even more than the total RAM in the device.
- Are there any other PostgreSQL parameters I should consider?

Comment: Perhaps there is something else running; your settings look good. When you calculate the total resident stack size, do you count shared buffers for each connection? The "proportional stack size" might be more appropriate.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I count what appears on the OOM killer report. Is there a way to exclude shared buffers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PostgreSQL uses several background processes, in addition to the "user" backends.  Things like wal writer, background writer, checkpointer, archiver, WAL senders, autovacuum workers, etc.  These (probably) aren't the problem, they just complicate the report.  It would be nice if the process name included that information, which it does (or can, depending on configuration) in top and ps, but apparently not in the OOM report.  Look in the db server log file to see what the killed process actually was.  It will not be a complete report, but better than what you currently know.

Most of the RSS is probably the portion of shared_buffers which each process has touched, which is the same part as all of the other processes have also touched.  So it is the same memory counted over and over again.  Just summing that column doesn't give you real answer.

If you had turned off overcommit, you would get a nice report in the db server's log file about what the process was and what it was doing when it ran out of memory, and where that memory was going.  But since you have the kernel configured to just randomly nuke things, you don't get that.  Processes which no longer exist can't generate error reports.

If you have a windowing system installed, you can't feasibly turn off over commit, since those will rampantly over allocate RAM they will never try to use.  But it doesn't look like you are running one of those, so there is probably no reason not to just do what the docs say to do.

Comment: I have included the db server log in my question, I will further investigate into TimescaleDB background worker. I will also turn off overcommit.